# Rails 3 CSS3 font not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Application.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Futura-Light";
  src: url("/assets/Futura-Light.ttf") format("truetype"); /* For IE */
  src: local("Futura-Light"), url("/assets/Futura-Light.ttf") format("truetype"); /* For non-IE */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#wrap {width:730px;position:relative;font-family:"Futura-Light";}
```

I have added this to application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

And I can download the font when visiting: `http://localhost:3000/assets/Futura-Light.ttf`

Why is the font not loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the /assets/  is your urls. Rails will add this for you, because in development and production these paths may differ.

```
  src: url("Futura-Light.ttf") format("truetype"); /* For IE */
  src: local("Futura-Light"), url("Futura-Light.ttf") format("truetype"); /* For non-IE */
```

Answer (score 0):

its good to write the path of the font files by using **asset_path** shown below.

`src: url(<%= asset_path 'Futura-Light.ttf' %>) format('truetype'); /* For IE */
src: local("Futura-Light"), url(<%= asset_path 'Futura-Light.ttf' %>) format('truetype'); /* For non-IE */`